# Multi-Dimensional Array ( C++ )

Tags: c++, pointers, multidimensional-array, memory-management

I'm trying to store a pointer in an array.

My pointer to a pointer is class object is:

```
classType **ClassObject;
```

So i know i can allocate it by using the new operator like this:

```
ClassObject = new *classType[ 100 ] = {};
```

I'm reading a text file, with punctuation and here is what i have so far:

```
// included libraries
// main function
// defined varaibles

classType **ClassObject; // global object
const int NELEMENTS = 100; // global index


wrdCount = 1;  // start this at 1 for the 1st word
while ( !inFile.eof() )  
{
   getline( inFile, str, '\n' );  // read all data into a string varaible
   str = removePunct(str);  // User Defined Function to remove all punctuation.
   for ( unsigned x = 0; x < str.length(); x++ )
   {
       if ( str[x] == ' ' ) 
       {
          wrdCount++;  // Incrementing at each space
          ClassObject[x] = new *classType[x];
       // What i want to do here is allocate space for each word read from the file.

       }
   }
}
// this function just replaces all punctionation with a space
string removePunct(string &str) 
{ 
    for ( unsigned x = 0; x < str.length(); x++ )
        if ( ispunct( str[x] ) )
            str[x] = ' ';
  return str;
}

// Thats about it.
```

I guess my questions are:

- Have I allocated space for each word in the file?
- How would i store a pointer in the ClassObject array within my while/for loop?

Comment: you need to read http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help and reformat your question to be more readable.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using C++ use the [Boost Multidimensional Array Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html)

Comment: And you should look at this question too : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/365782/how-do-i-best-handle-dynamic-multi-dimensional-arrays-in-c-c/365800#365800

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, I'm not sure what you want to do (especially new *classType[x] -- does this even compile?)

If you want a new classType for every word, then you can just go

```
ClassObject[x] = new classType; //create a _single_ classType
ClassObject[x]->doSomething();
```

provided that ClassObject is initialized (as you said).

You say you want a 2D array - if you want to do that, then the syntax is:

```
ClassObject[x] = new classType[y]; //create an array of classType of size y
ClassObject[0][0].doSomething(); //note that [] dereferences automatically
```

However, I'm also not sure of what you mean by new *classType[ 100 ] = {}; - what are the curly braces doing there? It seems like it should be

```
classType** classObject = new classType*[100];
```

I highly suggest you use something else, though, as this is really nasty (and you have to take care of deletion... ugh)

Use vector<>s or as the above poster suggested, the boost libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is perfectly fine excepting one line:
`ClassObject[x] = new *classType[x];`
The star * needs to go away, and what you're probably trying to say is that you want ClassObject to be indexed to *word count* rather than x.

Replace that line with:
`ClassObject[wrdCount] = new classType[x];`

Hope that helps,
Billy3

Comment: Im trying to pass the 1 word to the constructor, which takes a const character pointer paramater. I can call every function except for that one. Having ClassObject[][].WhatIneed( cArray ); wont work

ClassObject[][].WhatIdontNeed(); works