# How to use a "vector of vector"?

Tags: c++, stl, vector

I already searched on the web for it but I didn't get satisfying results.

I want to create something like

```
vector< vector<int*> > test_vector;
```

How do i fill this vector of vector? How to access it's members? Maybe someone knows some nice tutorials on the web?

kind regards
mikey

Comment: I would surely not use int* as the content of your vector. If you're storing numbers, just use int (or double/float/...). The use of pointers makes you have to delete each of them when your vector gets destroyed. Otherwise, you'll get a memory leak.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/823562/multi-dimensional-vector

Comment: I know your concern, but that code snippet above was only a demonstration. In effect I have to deal with pointers to objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remember that each element of `test_vector` is of type `vector<int*>`.  You would fill `test_vector` by filling each element vector.

You can access this just like any multi-dimensional array.  See:

```
int *p = test_vector[0][0];
```

Or:

```
int *p = test_vector.at(0).at(0);
```

Comment: Thanks! I reconsidered the problem and in order I wrote some test programms which helped me in my understanding!

Answer (score 1):

A question similar to yours was posted at DreamInCode: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/37527-vector-of-vectors/

Answer (score 1):

PS
If you want to use some kind of a matrix, I would prefer to use only one dimensional vector and map the access (because of performance).

For example Matrix M with m rows and n columns: you can map call

M[i][j] = x to M[i*n+j] = x.

Comment: This assumes the OP wants each of the interior vectors to be the same size... which may not be the problem at hand.

Comment: Therefore I use Matrix in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You fill a vector of vectors by putting vectors in it.

You access its members the same way you would any other vector.