# Traversing a multi array with pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

```
for ( j = 0; j < d1; j++ ){

    m += j;
        for ( i = 0; i < d1*d2; i +=d2){
        cout << *(m+i);
        }
    cout << endl;
}
```

d1,d2 are array dimensions

and

```
int* m = new int [d1*d2];
```

I want to traverse over my array and simply group and print the columns.Can't figure what's wrong with this code.Seems to be working fine untill the 3rd iteration in the following example:

Let's say my input values are `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`

I get:

```
1 4 7

2 5 8

4 7 (something random)
```

Comment: You are going out of bounds on your array. If you are using C++, use a multi-dimensional vector instead. [Multi-dimensional vector - How To](http://stackoverflow.com/a/823600/195488)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In

```
m += j;
```

you are first incrementing `m` by 0, then by one, then by 2. If we originally took a copy

```
int *start = m;
```

then in the first iteration of the outer loop, we'd have

```
m == start
```

in the second,

```
m == start + 1
```

in the third

```
m == start + 3
```

You'd want `m == start + 2` there. Except that you want to keep `m` in order to `delete` it at the end, so you shouldn't change `m` at all but use something like

```
for ( j = 0; j < d2; j++ ){

        for ( i = j; i < d1*d2; i +=d2){
        cout << *(m+i);
        }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Just a small mistake i guess:First iteration has to be j < d2 i guess.Else it disfunctions when row number is smaller than column number.

Comment: @user2362377 Right, and with non-square matrices, the `*(m+i+j)` could also access out-of-bounds, so I fixed that too now.

Answer (score 1):

```
m = &a[0];
for ( j = 0; j < d1; j++ )
{
    for ( i = 0; i < d2; i++)
        cout << *m++;
    cout << endl;
}
```