# Generate Arbitrarily Nested Vectors in C++

Tags: c++, vector

I am trying to write a function in order to generate arbitrarily nested vectors and initialize with the given specific value in C++. For example, `auto test_vector = n_dim_vector_generator<2, long double>(static_cast<long double>(1), 1);` is expected to create a "test_vector" object which type is `std::vector<std::vector<long double>>`.  The content of this test_vector should as same as the following code.

```cpp
    std::vector<long double> vector1;
    vector1.push_back(1);
    std::vector<std::vector<long double>> test_vector;
    test_vector.push_back(vector1);
```

The more complex usage of the n_dim_vector_generator function:

```
auto test_vector2 = n_dim_vector_generator<15, long double>(static_cast<long double>(2), 3);
```

In this case, the parameter `static_cast<long double>(2)` is as the data in vectors and the number `3` is as the push times. So, the content of this test_vector2 should as same as the following code.

```
    std::vector<long double> vector1;
    vector1.push_back(static_cast<long double>(2));
    vector1.push_back(static_cast<long double>(2));
    vector1.push_back(static_cast<long double>(2));
    std::vector<std::vector<long double>> vector2;
    vector2.push_back(vector1);
    vector2.push_back(vector1);
    vector2.push_back(vector1);
    std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<long double>>> vector3;
    vector3.push_back(vector2);
    vector3.push_back(vector2);
    vector3.push_back(vector2);
    //...Totally repeat 15 times in order to create test_vector2
    std::vector<...std::vector<long double>> test_vector2;
    test_vector2.push_back(vector14);
    test_vector2.push_back(vector14);
    test_vector2.push_back(vector14);
```

The detail to implement n_dim_vector_generator function is as follows.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
struct n_dim_vector_type;

template <typename T>
struct n_dim_vector_type<T, 0> {
    using type = T;
};

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
struct n_dim_vector_type {
    using type = std::vector<typename n_dim_vector_type<T, N - 1>::type>;
};


template<std::size_t N, typename T>
typename n_dim_vector_type<T,N>::type n_dim_vector_generator(T t, unsigned int);

template <std::size_t N, typename T>
typename n_dim_vector_type<T, N>::type n_dim_vector_generator<N, T>(T input_data, unsigned int push_back_times) {
    if (N == 0)
    {
        return std::move(input_data);
    }
    typename n_dim_vector_type<T, N>::type return_data;
    for (size_t loop_number = 0; loop_number < push_back_times; loop_number++)
    {
        return_data.push_back(n_dim_vector_generator<N - 1, T>(input_data, push_back_times));
    }
    return return_data;
}
```

As a result, I got an error `'return': cannot convert from 'long double' to 'std::vector<std::vector<long double,std::allocator<long double>>,std::allocator<std::vector<long double,std::allocator<long double>>>>'` I know that it caused by `if (N == 0)` block which is as the terminate condition to recursive structure. However, if I tried to edit the terminate condition into separate form.

```cpp
template <typename T>
inline T n_dim_vector_generator<0, T>(T input_data, unsigned int push_back_times) {
    return std::move(input_data);
}

template <std::size_t N, typename T>
typename n_dim_vector_type<T, N>::type n_dim_vector_generator<N, T>(T input_data, unsigned int push_back_times) {
    typename n_dim_vector_type<T, N>::type return_data;
    for (size_t loop_number = 0; loop_number < push_back_times; loop_number++)
    {
        return_data.push_back(n_dim_vector_generator<N - 1, T>(input_data, push_back_times));
    }
    return return_data;
}
```

The error `'n_dim_vector_generator': illegal use of explicit template arguments` happened. Is there any better solution to this problem?

The develop environment is in Windows 10 1909 with Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 Version 16.4.3

Comment: My advice is to not do this.  Multidimensional vectors lack data locality and can become a performance bottleneck.  It is more efficient, and easier to implement if you wrap a  1d vector in a class that can fake it has multiple dimensions using math.  Something along the lines of this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43358434/4342498

Comment: To simplify what @NathanOliver said, you might already know that arr2D[i][j] is similar to arr1D[i * k + j] by simply modifying the control loop. This basic idea can be extended to N dimensions.

Comment: Thanks to @NathanOliver for prompt reply. Due to some reasons on the project which I am working on. I want to design this kind of function for testing purpose.

Comment: Thanks to @Ardent for prompt reply and detailed description. Considering the characteristics and convenience in usage of std::vector, I think that std::vector is safer in memory management and more function-completed than arr2D. I know that using smart pointer could implement memory-safe arr2D, but it is hard to deal with multi-dimensional allocation in this way.

Comment: To clarify, are you looking for this strange 1-element multi-dimensional vector specifically, or are you looking for a general multi-dimensional data structure?

Comment: @parktomatomi The function n_dim_vector_generator should generate arbitrary multi-dimensional data structure base on the input parameters. The mentioned example illustrate the simple usage. In more complex usage: `auto test_vector = n_dim_vector_generator<15, long double>(static_cast<long double>(2), 3);`

Comment: @JimmyHu can you clarify what the meaning of 2 and 3 in your example are?

Comment: @parktomatomi To describe the meaning of parameter `static_cast<long double>(2)` and `3`, I already edit the content of this question above. Please check. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for editing. I updated my answer

Comment: Thanks to @parktomatomi for providing the answer. It's really a solution I expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve your specific mapping of:

```cpp
auto test_vector = n_dim_vector_generator<2, long double>(2, 3)
```

to a 3x3 vector filled with 2's, your template can be a bit simpler if you take advantage of this `vector` constructor:

```cpp
std::vector<std::vector<T>>(COUNT, std::vector<T>(...))
```

Since `vector` is copyable, this will fill COUNT slots with a different copy of the vector. So...

```cpp
template <size_t N, typename T>
struct n_dim_vector_generator {
    using type = std::vector<typename n_dim_vector_generator<N-1, T>::type>;
    type operator()(T value, size_t size) {
        return type(size, n_dim_vector_generator<N-1, T>{}(value, size));
    }
};

template <typename T>
struct n_dim_vector_generator<0, T> {
    using type = T;
    type operator()(T value, size_t size) {
        return value;
    }
};
```

usage:

```cpp
auto test_vector = n_dim_vector_generator<2, long double>{}(2, 3);
```

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/eiDAUG

---

For the record, to address some concerns from the comments, C++ *has* an idiomatic, initializable, contiguous-memory class equivalent of a multi-dimension C array: a nested `std::array`:

```cpp
std::array<std::array<long double, COLUMNS>, ROWS> test_array = { /*...*/ };

for (auto& row : test_array)
    for (auto cell : row)
        std::cout << cell << std::endl;
```

If you wanted to reduce the boilerplate to declare one, you can use a struct for that:

```cpp
template <typename T, size_t... N>
struct multi_array;

template <typename T, size_t NFirst, size_t... N>
struct multi_array<T, NFirst, N...> {
    using type = std::array<typename multi_array<T, N...>::type, NFirst>;
};

template <typename T, size_t NLast>
struct multi_array<T, NLast> {
    using type = std::array<T, NLast>;
};

template <typename T, size_t... N>
using multi_array_t = typename multi_array<T, N...>::type;
```

Then to use:

```cpp
multi_array_t<long double, ROWS, COLUMNS> test_array = { /*...*/ };

for (auto& row : test_array)
    for (auto cell : row)
        std::cout << cell << std::endl;
```

This is allocated on the stack, like a C array. That will eat up your stack space for a big array of course. But you can make a decorator range around `std::unique_ptr` to make a pointer to one a bit easier to access:

```cpp
template <typename T, size_t... N>
struct dynamic_multi_array : std::unique_ptr<multi_array_t<T, N...>> {
    using std::unique_ptr<multi_array_t<T, N...>>::unique_ptr;
    constexpr typename multi_array_t<T, N...>::value_type& operator [](size_t index) { return (**this)[index]; }
    constexpr const typename multi_array_t<T, N...>::value_type& operator [](size_t index) const { return (**this)[index]; }
    constexpr typename multi_array_t<T, N...>::iterator begin() { return (**this).begin(); }
    constexpr typename multi_array_t<T, N...>::iterator end() { return (**this).end(); }
    constexpr typename multi_array_t<T, N...>::const_iterator begin() const { return (**this).begin(); }
    constexpr typename multi_array_t<T, N...>::const_iterator end() const { return (**this).end(); }
    constexpr typename multi_array_t<T, N...>::const_iterator cbegin() const { return (**this).cbegin(); }
    constexpr typename multi_array_t<T, N...>::const_iterator cend() const { return (**this).cend(); }
    constexpr typename multi_array_t<T, N...>::size_type size() const { return (**this).size(); }
    constexpr bool empty() const { return (**this).empty(); }
    constexpr typename multi_array_t<T, N...>::value_type* data() { return (**this).data(); }
    constexpr const typename multi_array_t<T, N...>::value_type* data() const { return (**this).data(); }
};
```

*(let the buyer beware if you use those methods with `nullptr`)*

Then you can still brace-initialize a `new` expression and use it like a container:

```cpp
dynamic_multi_array<long double, ROWS, COLUMNS> test_array {
    new multi_array_t<long double, ROWS, COLUMNS> { /* ... */ }
};

for (auto& row : test_array)
    for (auto cell : row)
        std::cout << cell << std::endl;
```

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/lUwVE_