# How to return multi- dimensional-vector of given dimension and type?

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, stdvector, function-templates

Is it possible in modern c++ to write a function that, given a number `n` and a *type*, return a *n-dimensional vector* type.

```
 1,float -> return std::vector<float>
 2,float -> return std::vector<std::vector<float>>
```

and so on...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43358369/c-n-nested-vectors-at-runtime/43358434#43358434

Comment: What does "given a number n" mean?

Comment: Fun fact : Multidimensional arrays are not build in yet, but it is being worked on [Multidimensional C++ - Bryce Adelstein Lelbach - CppNorth 2022](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aFCLmQEkPUw)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a compile time approach using [template specialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization). We apply `std::vector<>` recursively until we reach the specialization for `N == 0`, where the final `type` is set to `T`:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>

template<std::size_t N, typename T>
struct recursive_vector {
    using type = std::vector<typename recursive_vector<N - 1, T>::type>;
};
template<typename T>
struct recursive_vector<0, T> {
    using type = T;
};

template<std::size_t N, typename T>
using vec = recursive_vector<N, T>::type;
```

so `vec<3, float>` becomes `vector<vector<vector<float>>>`:

```
int main() {
    vec<3, float> v;

    using std::vector;
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(v), vector<vector<vector<float>>>>);
}
```

[Try out the code, here](https://godbolt.org/z/aMcWxzzEh).

Comment: sorry for not specify that. What if I need a run-time solution?

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible in modern C++ to write a function that given a number `n` and a type return a `n-dimensional vector` type?

**Compile time**

If `n` is known at compile time, the job easy, which is already given in the other answer. Alternatively, you could also do:

```
#include <vector>

template<typename T, std::size_t N>
struct vec : public vec<std::vector<T>, N - 1u> {};

template<typename T> struct vec<T, 0u> { using type = T; };
template<typename T, std::size_t N> using vec_t = typename vec<T, N>::type;
```

Now `vec_t<float, 5u>` means `std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<float>>>>>`

***([See a live demo in godbolt.org](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/3EYbn84Ef))***

---

**Run time**

When `n` is run time depended, one possible solution is to wrap the possible multidimensional vectors types to [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) (Since [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17)).

Following is an example code.

```
#include <vector>
#include <variant> // std::variant

// type aliases for the multi-dim vectors
template<typename T> using Vec1D = std::vector<T>;
template<typename T> using Vec2D = Vec1D<Vec1D<T>>;
template<typename T> using Vec3D = Vec1D<Vec2D<T>>;
// ... so on (hope that you wouldn't need more than 4 or 5!)

template<typename T>
using VecVariants = std::variant<Vec1D<T>, Vec2D<T>, Vec3D<T>/*, so on ...*/>;

template<typename T> auto getVector_of(const std::size_t n)
{
    if (n == 1) return VecVariants<T>{Vec1D<T>{}};
    if (n == 2) return VecVariants<T>{Vec2D<T>{}};
    if (n == 3) return VecVariants<T>{Vec3D<T>{}};
    // ... so on
    return VecVariants<T>{Vec3D<T>{}}; // some default return!
}

template<typename T> void doSomething(const VecVariants<T>& vec)
{
    std::visit([](auto&& arg) {
        using Type = std::decay_t<decltype(arg)>;
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<Type, Vec1D<T>>)
            std::cout << "... do something with Vec1D\n";
        else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<Type, Vec2D<T>>)
            std::cout << "... do something with Vec2D\n";
        else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<Type, Vec3D<T>>)
            std::cout << "... do something with Vec3D\n";
        // .... so on
        else
            std::cout << "... default!\n";
        }, vec);
}
```

Now you can pass run time `n`

```
int main()
{
    std::size_t n{ 5 };
    while (n)
        doSomething(getVector_of<float>(n--)); // n must be 0u < n <= MAX_n you defined!
}
```

***([See a live demo in godbolt.org](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/z4TfnY89W))***