# Passing 2D array through the class in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I would like to create a 2D array of floats, pass it through a certain class, which changes the elements of the array in one of its functions and returns this array back. Importantly, I do not want to create a copy of my array inside the class. What is the best way to do that? I read that people suggest using big 1D array instead of 2D, some people recommend using vectors. That is the most effective (in terms of time) method to do it?

Comment: what do you mean by "..which changes the columns of the array in..." ?

Comment: Are looking for [In-place matrix transposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_matrix_transposition)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrays are passed by reference in C++, so if you just pass the array into whatever function you need to change it, then it will keep those changes. No need for anything complicated. Basically just:

```
type array[num1][num2];
//fill it with values here
yourObject.arrayChanger(array);
```

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13937325/942596) is a 2d array implementation using a single vector. Its a template so you just make a array_2d and everything works as it should.

**There are a few advantages to this method:**

- No need to worry about the array decaying into a pointer
- A 1D vector does not fragment memory like a `std::vector<std::vector<float> >`
- Memory management is done for you, so the chances of a memory leak is minimal.

Comment: Thank you andre, I like this way! I recommend everybody to look through this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2216017/dynamical-two-dimension-array-according-to-input/2216055#2216055)

Comment: I think this topic is also interesting: [2d array representation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1946830/multidimensional-variable-size-array-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

```
 #include <string>
 #include <iterator>
 #include <iostream>
 #include <algorithm>
 #include <array>

 using std::array ;

 array< array<int, 10 > , 20 > a ; //declared 20x10 2 dimension array
```