# C++ passing/accessing matrix by pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, segmentation-fault, pass-by-reference

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [2D arrays with C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1285457/2d-arrays-with-c)

Hi, I'm trying to copy a pointer to a matrix that i'm passing in to a function in C++. here's what my code is trying to express

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void func( char** p  )
{
    char** copy = p;
    cout << **copy;
}

int main()
{   
    char x[5][5];
    x[0][0] = 'H';
    func( (char**) &x);
    return 0;
}
```

However, this gives me a Seg Fault. Would someone please explain (preferrably in some detail) what underlying mechanism i'm missing out on? (and the fix for it)

Thanks much in advance :)

Comment: A `char**` is **not** the same thing as a `char [][]`. Really. There are many questions in which this is discussed at length. I'll poke around a bit and find one or two.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1285457/2509 is c++ specific, and http://stackoverflow.com/q/917783/2509 http://stackoverflow.com/q/2003745/2509 http://stackoverflow.com/q/2003745/2509 are all tagged [c], but as far as using arrays and pointers go the issues are the same (note that there are more choices in c++).

Answer (score 1):

`char**` is a pointer to a pointer (or an array of pointers). `&x` is not one of those - it's a pointer to a two-dimensional array of chars, which can be implicitly converted to a pointer to a single char (`char *`). The compiler probably gave you an error, at which point you put in the cast, but the compiler was trying to tell you something important.

Comment: Actually, `&x` is a pointer to the entire 2D array. Its type is `char(*)[5][5]`.

Comment: @FredOverflow, I knew there was something amiss with my description but I didn't know the best way to word it - you helped me figure it out, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A pointer to an array of 5 arrays of 5 char (`char x[5][5]`) has the type "pointer to array of 5 arrays of 5 chars", that is `char(*p)[5][5]`. The type `char**` has nothing to do with this.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void func( char (*p)[5][5]  )
{
    char (*copy)[5][5] = p;
    cout << (*copy)[0][0];
}

int main()
{
    char x[5][5];
    x[0][0] = 'H';
    func(&x);
    return 0;
}
```

Of course there are many other ways to pass a 2D array by reference or pointer, as already mentioned in comments. The most in-detail reference is probably StackOverflow's own C++ FAQ, [How do I use arrays in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c/4810676#4810676)

Comment: Your way works, but only for the first element. Try setting x[1][1] to something like '-' in your main() and then retrieving it in "void func()", it won't work. i'll try to figure exactly why, guess i actually have to read up on this. thanks for suggesting

Comment: @David T: it works for every element: https://ideone.com/hAITL

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead of using a char**:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void func( char* &p  )
{
    char* copy = p;
    cout << copy[0];
}

int main()
{   
    char x[5][5];
    x[0][0] = 'H';
    func(&x[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This does nothing to do with NULL-terminating

Comment: I fixed my response, I though it was something else on first glance.

Comment: a single char doesn't need to be null terminated. It can't, actually.

Comment: Did you read the above comments before you wrote something?