# For-loop - Structure

Tags: c

I have this part of code:

```
for(i = 0; i < matrix->y; i++)
{
  printf("3.%i - %i %i\n", i, matrix->y, matrix->x);//write correct "3.0 - 3 4"
  for(j = 0; j < matrix->x; j++)
  {
    printf("N - %i %i\n", matrix->y, matrix->x);//never write anything
    fscanf(input, "%i", &grid[i][j]);
  }
  printf("3.%i - %i %i\n", i, matrix->y, matrix->x);//write wrong "3.0 - 3 0"
}
```

first printf outputs y=3 and x=4, but it never goes inside loop, it never reach the second printf inside for-loop. When I write the same printf from the first line after for-loop, it tels me y=3 and x=0.
Where I have done mistake.

Thanks.

Edit

Code is writen as it is. No lines skipped.

Matrix definition

```
typedef struct matrix
{
  int x;
  int y;
  int ** grid;
} Matrix;
```

i and j is defined by

```
int i, j;
```

Whole function

```
Matrix * loadMatrix(char * filename)
{
  Matrix * matrix;
  FILE * input;
  input = fopen(filename, "r");
  if (input == NULL)
    printError (ERR_READFILE);
  else
  {
    fscanf(input, "%i", &(matrix->y));
    fscanf(input, "%i", &(matrix->x));
    int i, j;
    int grid[matrix->y][matrix->x];
    matrix->grid = grid;
    printf("2 - %i %i\n", matrix->y, matrix->x);
    for(i = 0; i < matrix->y; i++)
    {
      printf("3.%i - %i %i\n", i, matrix->y, matrix->x);
      for(j = 0; j < matrix->x; j++)
    {
    printf("N - %i %i\n", matrix->y, matrix->x);
    fscanf(input, "%i", &grid[i][j]);
    }
    printf("3.%i - %i %i\n", i, matrix->y, matrix->x);
    fclose(input);
  }
  return matrix;
}
```

Comment: You should let us see the definition of your `matrix` structure.

Comment: If you show us the rest of the code then we can work out where you set `x=0`

Comment: I'm thinking something along the lines of `j` aliasing `matrix->x`

Comment: @pmg I removed the comment as it didn't make sense :-)

Comment: wild guess, did you write in your code before what we see the next line: "matrix = &j"?

Comment: If you repeat the first `printf()`, do you get the same data printed both times?  If not, it hints that `matrix` was a pointer to a local variable of a function that has since returned.

Comment: Any chance that `matrix` is not really pointing to a `Matrix`, but rather some random part of memory, and you just get lucky the first time?  Do any external threads have access to `matrix`?

Comment: No really show us the code. Stop showing fragments. Post a complete program.

Comment: it reads correct values x and y from given file(tried more values)

Comment: @BrianMcFarland: great guess. Real nice case if undefined behavior IMO, the behavior is surprising.

Comment: `%i` is not a valid (standard) format for `fscanf`. It can be used with the `printf` family only. You probably meant `%d`.

Comment: Moral of the story is to post minimal yet complete code. Now you should accept one of the answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your program's behavior is undefined because you're not allocating storage for `matrix`. So anything could happen.

Add this somewhere after you have declared `matrix` (just before the `fscanf` lines seems optimal):

```
matrix = malloc(sizeof(Matrix));
```

and change the line where you declare `matrix` to:

```
Matrix *matrix = NULL;
```

(otherwise you'll return garbage if the `fopen` fails.)

Second problem is that you're then also failing to allocate proper storage for `matrix->grid`. You can't keep a pointer to a local variable after the function has returned.

You'll need to create that storage with `malloc` or `calloc` too. See this question: [How do I work with dynamic mutli-dimensional arrays in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/917783/how-do-i-work-with-dynamic-multi-dimensional-arrays-in-c) for an example of how to do that.

You'll also need to take care to `free` both of those once you're finished using them.

Don't forget to `#include <stdlib.h>`, which is required for `malloc` and `free`.

Comment: If you add that just after the declaration of `matrix`, if won't work in pre-C99.

Comment: Gah, you're right, _and_ it wasn't a good idea to put it there anyway.

Comment: +1 for the `Matrix matrix = NULL`.  Because initializing pointers to NULL will (usually) result in a segfault if you attempt to dereference them.  Which makes this kind of bug result in well defined, easy to debug hard faults rather than bizarre, undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

> Where I have done mistake?

You haven't allocated space to access through your `matrix` **pointer**.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you never initialize `matrix`, which means it can point to anything. That can cause access violation errors (if you're lucky) or weird errors (if you aren't). To initialize it, use `malloc`:

```
matrix = malloc(sizeof(Matrix));
```

Don't forget to deallocate the memory when you don't need the `Matrix` anymore by using `free`.

You should also check that `malloc` didn't return `NULL`, which can happen when there isn't enough free memory available.