# Proper way to declare a variable length two dimensional array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, dynamic-sizing

I would like to get a two dimensional int array `arr` that I can access via arr[i][j].

As far as I understand I could declare `int arr[10][15];` to get such an array.
In my case the size is however variable and as far as I understand this syntax doesn't work if the size of the array isn't hardcoded but I use a variable like `int arr[sizeX][sizeY]`.

What's the best workaround?

Comment: Your question says C, but your tag says C++. Could you please clarify? Also, you're correct that using a variable to determine the size of the array isn't valid syntax unless `sizeX` and `sizeY` are `const`. However, gcc (or g++) support this unless you pass them the `-ansi` or `-pedantic` flags. I'd still recommend against using it as it's not standard C/C++.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you don't want to use a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) of vectors (or the new C++11 [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)) then you have to allocate all sub-arrays manually:

```
int **arr = new int* [sizeX];
for (int i = 0; i < sizeX; i++)
    arr[i] = new int[sizeY];
```

And of course don't forget to `delete[]` all when done.

Comment: @Some Programmer dude how to delete that? is this way true? delete []arr[] ?

Answer (score 1):

c/c++ does not support multidimensional array. But it does support array of array:

```
    //simulate 2-dimension array with 1-dimension array
    {
        int x = 20;
        int y = 40;
        int * ar = new int(x*y);
        int idx_x =9;
        int idx_y=12;
        ar[idx_x + idx_y * x] = 23;
    }
    //simulate 2-dimension array with array of array
    {
        int x = 20;
        int y = 40;
        int**ar = new int*[y];
        for(int i = 0; i< y; ++i)
        {
            ar[i] = new int[x];
        }
        ar[9][12] = 0;      
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for the solution in C, see this Stack Overflow thread:
[How do I work with dynamic multi-dimensional arrays in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/917783/how-do-i-work-with-dynamic-multi-dimensional-arrays-in-c).

If C++ is okay, then you can create a 2D vector, i.e. a vector of vectors. See http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/833/.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, with array syntax. The language requires that you use compile time constants to create arrays.

Comment: You can use an `int**` (or whatever type you want). Once you've correctly `malloc()`ed it, you can access elements using two subscript operators.

Comment: @Chris Parton: This is not array syntax. It's using pointers, and new, to emulate dynamically sized arrays.

Comment: I never said it was :) I was just making the point that it's possible for him to access elements using pointers in the same fashion as you would a multidimensional array. To that end, the syntax is the same; but I agree that using pointers like that isn't array syntax.

Answer (score 0):

C++ does not have variable length arrays. You can consider using `vector<vector<int> >`. It can be also accessed using `arr[i][j]`.

Answer (score 0):

As fefe said you can use vector of vectors, e. g. :

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
        vector< vector<int> > vec;
        vector<int> row1;
        row1.push_back(1);
        row1.push_back(2);
        vector<int> row2;
        row2.push_back(3);
        row2.push_back(4);

        vec.push_back(row1);
        vec.push_back(row2);

        for( int ix = 0; ix < 2; ++ix)
            for( int jx = 0; jx < 2; ++jx)
                cout << "[" << ix << ", " << jx << "] = " << vec[ix][jx] << endl;

}
```