# Dynamic Matrix problem. How could I fix this?

Tags: c

I'm attempting to create a dynamic Matrix with functions, but first I decided to segment the assignment so that I know everything works as it should. But the creation is not working.

I tried moving the parentheses, using different values, but it always crashes when i=2

```
int rows=4;
int columns=4;
int cont=1;
int ** Mat;
Mat=(int**)malloc(rows*columns*sizeof(int));
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
    {
        printf("%d",i);
        *(*(Mat+i)+j)=cont++;
    }
}
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
    {
        printf("%2d ", *(*(Mat+i)+j) );  /* a[i][j] */
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

I don't get any compilation errors, I would expect this
1234
5678
9101112
13141516

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic Multidimensional array in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8725364/dynamic-multidimensional-array-in-c)

Comment: See [Correctly allocating multi-dimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
int ** Mat;
Mat=(int**)malloc(rows*columns*sizeof(int));
```

to:

```
int (*Mat)[columns];
Mat = malloc(rows * sizeof *Mat);
```

`int ** Mat;` declares `Mat` to be a pointer to a pointer to an `int`. But to make that work, you have to allocate space for a bunch of pointers (one for each row) and fill them in with pointers to space allocated for the rows. You did not do that.

You allocated space for `rows * columns` `int`, and you set `Mat` to point to that space. It seems like you want to use `Mat` as a pointer to a matrix (or, properly, to the first row of a matrix), not as a pointer to pointers. So declare it as `int (*Mat)[columns];`, which makes it a pointer to an array of four columns (specifically, it is pointing to the first such array, which is followed by others).

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a bunch for the explanation! The assignment wants us to only use pointers and not [] to loop through the matrix so I was really confused, but this helped a ton!

Comment: How would you suggest I sent this to a function? Should I send it as int*Mat[]?

Comment: @W.Blengio: Declare a function parameter the same way as the pointer: `int (*Mat)[columns]`. Make sure `columns` is an earlier parameter.

Comment: @W.Blengio You can declare the function as `void func (int rows, int cols, int mat[rows][cols])`. This works because `int mat[rows][cols]` as a function parameter is equivalent to `int(*mat)[cols]`. Then call the function with `func(rows, cols, Mat)`, where `Mat` is a pointer of type `int (*Mat)[columns];`.

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation is using a jagged array. That is, the Mat is an array of pointers where each pointer points to a row. The only part of your code that is wrong is the initialization. When you create the pointer for your Mat, the pointers to the rows come from whatever memory malloc gave you, and thus or not valid. You need to initialize the pointer for each row.

```
Mat=(int**)malloc(rows*sizeof(int*));
for (int i=0;i<rows;++i) {
    Mat[i] = malloc(cols*sizeof(int));
}
```

Comment: This is worse than what the OP has, because it doesn't create a 2D array, but instead a slow, segmented look-up table. The correct solution is to change the `int**` to the correct pointer type.