# How to declare 2D array dynamically?

Tags: c, arrays, 2d, dynamic-allocation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I work with dynamic multi-dimensional arrays in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/917783/how-do-i-work-with-dynamic-multi-dimensional-arrays-in-c)

Is their any way to dynamically allocate 2D array like 1D array.

using

> malloc

or

> calloc

Comment: [Two second search on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/917783/how-do-i-work-with-dynamic-multi-dimensional-arrays-in-c)