# a matrix of pointers on object in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I assume this is basic question, but I'm not English and not used still with the terms of programming language, that's why I question here (I couldn't find).

*Here's my context:*

I have a structure (let's simplify it) as follow

```
struct _unit
{
  char value;
} Unit;
```

and in the main program, I'd like to have a row of pointers that points a row of other pointers pointing structures **Unit**.
Something like

```
int main ()
{
  Unit** units;

  ..

  printf("%d", units[0][0].value);

  ...
}
```

I get a little confused, what is the way to go so **Unit**'s can be accessed as a multi-dimensional array.

here's my try

```
{
  units = (Unit**)malloc(sizeof(void*));

  units[0][0] = (Unit*)malloc(sizeof(Unit));
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're almost there.

First, you need to declare your type, as you have, as `Unit**`. Then, on that, allocate enough `Unit*` pointers to hold the number of rows. Finally, loop over those created pointers, creating each `Unit`.

For example:

```
int i;
Unit** u;

// Allocate memory to store 50 pointers to your columns.    
u = malloc(sizeof(Unit*) * 50);

// Now, for each column, allocate 50 Units, one for each row.
for(i=0; i<50; i++) {
    u[i] = malloc(sizeof(Unit) * 50);
}

// You can now access using u[x][y];
```

That's the traditional way of doing it. C99 also introduced a different syntax to do this, as follows:

```
Unit (*u)[n] = malloc(sizeof(Unit[n][n])) // n = size of your matrix
```

From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12805980/235700

Answer (score 2):

You may have misunderstood the meaning of the struct declaration.

```
struct _unit
{
    char value;
} Unit;
```

The effect of your code is to declare a struct type `struct _unit` and allocate space for one variable of that type, named `Unit`.

What you probably meant to say is

```
struct _unit
{
    char value;
};

typedef struct _unit Unit;
```

In C, the word "struct" is part of the type unless you typedef it.