# two dimensional array as one dimensional array of pointers

Tags: c

Can I look at a two dimensional array as a one dimensional array of pointers, which the j index is a pointer to  the array of the j row of the matrix? 
For example if I have an array[4][4]. Is arr[2] the pointer to the second row array?

Comment: Do you look at a one dimensional array as simply a pointer?

Comment: Read section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com).

Answer (score 0):

No. The data is continuous in memory.

arr[2] would know the size of a single array and add 2 times that to the array pointer to get to the appropriate offset.

Comment: Depends on how it's created. If it's statically allocated with fixed dimensions, then you're right that the data are contiguous, but it's perfectly valid to declare `<sometype>** arr`, and allocate the actual dimensions later. I do that to get triangular form matrices, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

I may be true... It is the case if you allocated it that way : [How do I work with dynamic multi-dimensional arrays in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/917783/how-do-i-work-with-dynamic-multi-dimensional-arrays-in-c). However, the best way to go may to use something like `&arr[2][0]`. Bye, Francis

Answer (score 0):

> Can I look at a two dimensional array as a one dimensional array of pointers, which the j index is a pointer to the array of the j row of the matrix?

Yes. But always remember that *arrays are not pointers*. In case of 2D array `array[M][N]`, spaces are allocated for each of the array element `array[i]` (`i` is `int` here). But in case of array of pointers `*array[M]`, you need to allocate space for each element of `array`.

> For example if I have an array[4][4]. Is arr[2] the pointer to the second row array?

Yes. `arr2` decays to the pointer to the row 2