# 2D array access time comparison

Tags: c++, c, performance

I have two ways of constructing a 2D array:

```
int arr[NUM_ROWS][NUM_COLS];
//...
tmp = arr[i][j]
```

and flattened array

```
int arr[NUM_ROWS*NUM_COLS];
//...
tmp = arr[i*NuM_COLS+j];
```

I am doing image processing so even a little improvement in access time is necessary. Which one is faster? I am thinking the first one since the second one needs calculation, but then the first one requires two addressing so I am not sure.

Comment: It makes no difference - there are much more important considerations when it comes to performance, e.g. access pattern, stride, etc.

Comment: In general, the compiler has already precalculated the space required and the code calls the allocation function with the precalculated size.  No extra penalties for precalculation.

Comment: If you want to improve performance: 1) Use a fixed size array that is allocated at program start.  2) Search the web for "data cache optimization" for suggestions on how to allocate and use 2D arrays for maximum performance from the processor's data cache.

Comment: For image processing it's unlikely you can use statically allocated arrays for the imaging.  In that case your question depends on how you allocate the dynamic 2D arrays.  See my answer.

Comment: @PaulR, since this is for image processing I assume that the OP will need dynamic arrays.  In that case it does make a difference how 2D dynamic arrays are allocated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is any performance difference. System will allocate same amount of contiguous memory in both cases. For calculate `i*Numcols+j`, either you would do it for 1D array declaration, or system would do it in 2D case. Only concern is ease of usage.

Comment: Note that this doesn't hold for dynamic truly two-dimensional arrays.

Comment: Ya but OP was asked for static allocation, which is allocated before run time.

Comment: Sure, just to note :)

Comment: @lisyarus, could you explain more about what you mean by "that this doesn't hold for dynamic truly two-dimensional arrays"?

Comment: @Zboson: if you create a two-dimensional array as `int **a = new int* [NUM_ROWS];` and so on, the compiler won't be able to optimize it to linear array. I know, it's quite obvious, just a note.

Comment: @lisyarus, actually, you can make a linear array if you do it right, see my answer.

Comment: @Zboson: in your answer a linear array is created manually; that's not the case I'm talking about.

Answer (score 1):

You should have trust into the capabilities of your compiler in optimizing standard code.

Also you should have trust into modern CPUs having fast numeric multiplication instructions.

Don't bother to use one or another!

I - decades ago - optimized some code greatly by using pointers instead of using 2d-array-calculation --> but this will a) only be useful if it is an option to store the pointer - e.g. in a loop and b) have low impact since i guess modern cpus should do 2d array access in a single cycle? Worth measuring! May be related to the array size.

In any case pointers using ptr++ or ptr += NuM_COLS will for sure be a little bit faster if applicable!

Answer (score 0):

The first method will almost always be faster.  IN GENERAL (because there are always corner cases) processor and memory architecture as well as compilers may have optimizations built in to aid with 2d arrays or other similar data structures.  For example, GPUs are optimized for matrix (2d array) math.

So, again in general, I would allow the compiler and hardware to optimize your memory and address arithmetic if possible.

...also I agree with @Paul R, there are much bigger considerations when it comes to performance than your array allocation and address arithmetic.

Comment: Could you take a look at the assembly language?  I'm definitely sure that both cases are a single call to the memory allocation function with a hard-coded constant value.

Comment: Take for example the case where the array size is a power of 2 like 16 or 32 rows by 8 or 64 columns.  A compiler might substitute multiplication with bit shifting to get an element address.  If you hard code the calculation then you're guaranteed to be slower in that case.  Again, I don't think there is any benefit in performing you're own address calculations unless there is a unique need for it.

Comment: If the array size is a fixed size, the compiler has performed the size calculation before emitting code.  For array sizes determined at run-time, the compiler must emit code to perform the calculation.  Two big different performances.

Comment: There's a multiplication left out here which is sizeof(int) * NUM_ROWS * NUM_COLS.  Couldn't that be optimized at run time?

Comment: If NUM_ROWS and NUM_COLS are constants, it will be calculated during compile time.  Do you need constants calculated during run-time?

Answer (score 0):

Since your goal is image processing then I would assume your images are too large for static arrays. The correct question you should be about dynamically allocated arrays

In C/C++ there are multiple ways you can allocate a dynamic 2D array [How do I work with dynamic multi-dimensional arrays in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/917783/how-do-i-work-with-dynamic-multi-dimensional-arrays-in-c). To make this work in both C/C++ we can use malloc with casting (for C++ only you can use new)

Method 1:

```
int** arr1 = (int**)malloc(NUM_ROWS * sizeof(int*));
for(int i=0; i<NUM_ROWS; i++)
    arr[i] = (int*)malloc(NUM_COLS * sizeof(int));
```

Method 2:

```
int** arr2 = (int**)malloc(NUM_ROWS * sizeof(int*));
int* arrflat = (int*)malloc(NUM_ROWS * NUM_COLS * sizeof(int));
for (int i = 0; i < dimension1_max; i++)
  arr2[i] = arrflat + (i*NUM_COLS);
```

Method 2 essentially creates a contiguous 2D array: i.e. `arrflat[NUM_COLS*i+j]` and `arr2[i][j]` should have identical performance.  However, `arrflat[NUM_COLS*i+j]` and `arr[i][j]` from method 1 should not be expected to have identical performance since `arr1` is not contiguous.  Method 1, however, seems to be the method that is most commonly used for dynamic arrays.

In general, I use `arrflat[NUM_COLS*i+j]` so I don't have to think of how to allocated dynamic 2D arrays.

Answer (score 0):

There are two cases to consider:  compile time definition and run-time definition of the array size.  There is big difference in performance.

**Static allocation, global or file scope, fixed size array:**
The compiler knows the size of the array and tells the linker to allocate space in the data / memory section.  This is the fastest method.

Example:

```
#define ROWS 5
#define COLUMNS 6
int array[ROWS][COLUMNS];
int buffer[ROWS * COLUMNS];
```

**Run time allocation, function local scope, fixed size array:**
The compiler knows the size of the array, and tells the code to allocate space in the local memory (a.k.a. stack) for the array.  In general, this means adding a value to a stack register.  Usually one or two instructions.

Example:

```
void my_function(void)
{
  unsigned short my_array[ROWS][COLUMNS];
  unsigned short buffer[ROWS * COLUMNS];
}
```

**Run Time allocation, dynamic memory, fixed size array:**
Again, the compiler has already calculated the amount of memory required for the array since it was declared with fixed size.  The compiler emits code to call the memory allocation function with the required amount (usually passed as a parameter).  A little slower because of the function call and the overhead required to find some dynamic memory (and maybe garbage collection).

Example:

```
void another_function(void)
{
  unsigned char * array = new char [ROWS * COLS];
  //...
  delete[] array;
}
```

**Run Time allocation, dynamic memory, variable size:**
Regardless of the dimensions of the array, the compiler must emit code to calculate the amount of memory to allocate.  This quantity is then passed to the memory allocation function.  A little slower than above because of the code required to calculate the size.

Example:

```
int * create_board(unsigned int rows, unsigned int columns)
{
  int * board = new int [rows * cols];
  return board;
}
```