# C - create an array with malloc, then loop through it

Tags: c, arrays, loops, pointers, malloc

I'm learning C at the moment and tried to write this function

```
int *create_matrix(int n) {
   int *matrix = malloc(n*n*sizeof(int));
   srand(time(NULL));
   int i, j;
   for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        matrix[i][j] = rand()%10;
      }
   }
   return matrix;
}
```

why does this fail to compile? its complaining about `matrix[i][j]` is not an pointer/array. but I've just declared it as an pointer six lines above...

Comment: use matrix[i * n + j], you don't have a multidimensional array

Comment: Since you declared `int *matrix`, `matrix` is a pointer, but `matrix[i]` is an int, thus `matrix[i][j]` doesn't make sense (it's like saying `21[i] = rand()%10;`).

Comment: Thank you everyone for all the explaination! I clearly see my mistake now and it seems i'll need a little bit more practice with pointers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declare `matrix` as a one-dimensional array.  You need to either store the data in it as such, i.e.

```
matrix[i * n + j] = rand() % 10;
```

Or declare it as a two-dimensional array and allocate memory accordingly.

```
    int** matrix = malloc(n * sizeof(int*));
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        matrix[i] = malloc(n * sizeof(int));
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            matrix[i][j] = rand() % 10;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

It's a 1D array, so you have to treat it as a 1D array, and not as 2D.

You can of course still store your `n x n` elements in it:

```
    matrix[i * n + j] = rand() % 10;
```

If you prefer, you can set up a 2D structure by following the advice given in [How do I work with dynamic multi-dimensional arrays in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/917783/how-do-i-work-with-dynamic-multi-dimensional-arrays-in-c)

By the way, you probably don't want to be calling `srand()` every time you create a matrix. If you call `create_matrix()` twice in quick succession, you could end up getting the same "random" matrix. Call `srand()` once at the start of your program.

Answer (score 2):

You've declared `matrix` as a one-dimensional array, and not as a two-dimensional array.
So use it like:

```
for(int i=0; i<n*n; ++i)
    matrix[i] = //whatever;
```

If you really need two-dimensional array, you need to use double `pointers`:

```
int **matrix = malloc(n * sizeof(int *));  // notice the double pointer
// ....
// ....
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    matrix[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
    // ....
}
```

Comment: You also need to allocate the rows if you are going for a two-dimensional approach.

Comment: I think that's obvious! I was just suggesting a way how it could be approached.

Comment: It's obvious to me and perhaps to you but the issue here is that you've half-suggested another way of doing something, making your answer incomplete. It would be a lot more useful to show the full approach, or simply leave it out entirely as others have already explained it in more depth.

Answer (score 1):

What it's really complaining about is, the matrix[i] is not a pointer/array. You've only created a 1-dimensional array, you either can access it directly like

```
matrix[i * n + j] = rand() % 10;
```

or go ahead, do it cleanly, and redo the array, so it will be 2-dimensional. You'll need to use pointer to a pointer (for every member in line - one row)

```
int **matrix
```

but you'll have to loop trough the

```
*matrix
```

to malloc each row by itself.

Look up on 2-dimensional arrays.

//EDIT: Also, move the srand() to the beginning of the file. You don't want to srand() with every new matrix.

Answer (score 1):

You want two dimensions, then you need a pointer to pointer (not a single pointer):

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int **create_matrix(int n)
{
   int **matrix = malloc(n * sizeof(int *));
   srand(time(NULL));
   int i, j;
   for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      matrix[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
      for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
         matrix[i][j] = rand()%10;
      }
   }
   return matrix;
}

int main(void)
{    
    int **matrix = create_matrix(5);
    return 0;
}
```