# Function is returning the pointer for the same as before

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to make a function that creates a personalized array and return the pointer to it. I've the following code:

```
int (*newArray())[COLUNAS] {

    static int thisIsTheNewArray[LINHAS][COLUNAS];
    /* some changes */
    return thisIsTheNewArray;
}
```

Then, I have:

```
int (*tabuleiroJogador)[COLUNAS] = newArray();
int (*tabuleiroComputador)[COLUNAS] = newArray();
```

The problem here is that if I change `tabuleiroJogador` I also change `tabuleiroComputador`. I don't know why this is happenning. I think it's related with the `static` keyword and it returns always the same instance.

The arrays should be **different**.

Comment: This is c. I printed the pointers of that two arrays and both points to the same local. :(

Comment: You have pointers to the same array (because of `static`). You can allocate dynamically instead and return a pointer to the first element.

Comment: Yes, there is only one instance of the array and you're returning a handle to it.

Comment: Inside the function, define a pointer, allocate memory dynamically using `malloc()`, do the operation and return the pointer.

Comment: So, how should I do instead?

Comment: STATIC !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does "static" mean in a C program?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/572547/what-does-static-mean-in-a-c-program)

Comment: Hmm... thanks. I'm going to try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`static` in this context means that the array will maintain it's value between calls to the `newArray()` function.

If you want a different copy of the array each time `newArray` is called, you will need to dynamically create it.  You will also need to be sure that it is properly deallocated when you are finished.

```
int* newArray(int lines, int columns)
{
   return malloc(sizeof(int) * lines * columns);
}

int* arr = newArray();
/* later... */
free(arr);
```

**Note:**  This has slightly different semantics than your original, in that it allocates enough space but the array will be indexed in a single dimension.

Comment: Thank you. This answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/917783/how-do-i-work-with-dynamic-multi-dimensional-arrays-in-c) also helped me.

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned, you have to use `malloc` if you want different calls to the function to create different instances.

(Well, you don't *have* to; you could use a table of static arrays, if you know at the start of the program exactly how many different arrays you need).

The code for malloc could be:

```
int (*newArray())[COLUNAS]
{
    int (*p)[COLUNAS] = calloc(LINHAS, sizeof *p);
    return p;
}
```

---

In case you had overlooked the possibility; the arrays could have been created without using a function:

```
int tabuleiroJogador[LINHAS][COLUNAS];
int tabuleiroComputador[LINHAS][COLUNAS];
```

or using malloc:

```
int (*tabuleiroJogador)[COLUNAS] = calloc(LINHAS, sizeof *tabuleiroJogador);
int (*tabuleiroComputador)[COLUNAS] = calloc(LINHAS, sizeof *tabuleiroComputador);
```

Answer (score 0):

`static` variables in a function share the same memory space across multiple calls, and this is why we love them. This property allows the variable to retain it's value across the calls, giving it global-like functionality. To dynamically allocate memory for your needs, use the specialized functions like `malloc`.

Comment: This is why we *hate* them.

Comment: @Puppy If you hate them - don't use them. But sometimes they are needed.

Comment: Only if you're a terrible programmer who wants to help other programmers become even worse.