# What exactly happens when accessing a 2D array

Tags: c++, c

I've been coding for quite a while, but just realized that my interperation of a very elementary operation may be confused.

```
int array[10][10];

array[1][1] = 0;
```

This is sample enough - address of array + (10 * 1 + 1) * sizeof(int) is assigned 0.

But what about when doing dynamic arrays?

```
int **array;

// malloc/new the base array of pointers - say 10 as above.
array = malloc(10 * sizeof(int *));

// through pointers and alloc each with ints - again 10 per row as above.
for(int i=0; i<10; i++) 
    array[i] = malloc(10 * sizeof(int);

array[1][1] = 0;
```

In this example, the compiler has to reference an array on the first layer of the array to get to the second pointer to get to memory. Again, this process is straight forward.

My question here is: How does the compiler know that memory  is contiguous and therefore it can just do simple math instead of a reference in the first example, but not the second?

If the answer is: because the compiler knows the size of the array beforehand, so be it, but is there a way to tell the compiler that the dynamic array is a single allocation and therefore it can do the simpler math instead of the extra deref and extra memory fragmenting allocations?  Or does this require VLA support to get right as per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/917783/how-do-i-work-with-dynamic-multi-dimensional-arrays-in-c) which goes like:

```
double (*A)[n] = malloc(sizeof(double[n][n]));
```

Another website listed this as a possibility as well:

```
int r=3, c=4;
int **arr;

arr  = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int *) * r);
arr[0] = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * c * r);
```

Which really got me wondering about how the compiler is figuring things out, or if this is just another way of using VLA support.

For C++, there is boost and nested vectors, but they are even heavier than the above so again, I would avoid those if possible.

---

**Update**

Honestly, what I should do here is just compile my above examples and take a gander at the assembler output.  That would answer all my questions in no time at all. My misconception was that I assumed that all n-dim array access was done just by doing math similiar to how it is done with compile time known arrays.  I did not realize that [][] was doing double duty as `**array` with appropriate indexing between each dereference for dynamic allocs, while doing [i*dim+j] for compile time known types.  Dynamic 2+ Dimension arrays is just not something I ever have had to do.

Comment: One word: _types_. This is the reason we have types. Notice in particular how `int**` is different from `int[10][10]`, and that the latter _cannot_ decay to the former (it decays instead to `int(*)[10]` or something like that). I don't _really_ understand what you're asking because your whole question is (by definition) predicated on a fundamental misconception. Unfortunately, we don't yet know precisely what that misconception is. :) This would probably be better resolved in a chatroom.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The types `int **` and `int[10][10]` are not the same.

The type `int **` doesn't contain any information about how many elements there are, because it is not an array type, it is a pointer type (specifically a pointer to an `int *`). `int[10][10]` contains all the information the compiler needs to know how many elements there are.

You'll notice this if you try using `sizeof` on a pointer vs an array. The following program demonstrates this:

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                             

int main ( int argc, char * argv[] ) { 

    printf( "Size of int[10][10]: %lu\n", sizeof(int[10][10]) );
    printf( "Size of int**: %lu\n", sizeof(int**) );

    return 0;
}
```

Dynamic memory isn't allocated at compile time, it is compiled at run-time, so a compiler changing the way the dynamic memory is created, could end up modifying the behaviour of your program, (IE. by allocating more than is available in a contiguous block, and having malloc return null).

You can get a contiguous block of memory yourself of course, by allocating enough memory for `100 ints`, and then doing the arithmatic yourself:

```
int * mem = malloc( 10 * 10 * sizeof( int ) );
```

Now mem is a contiguous block of 100 ints

```
int * array[10];
for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
    array[i] = &mem[10*i];
```

Now you have an array of 10 `int *`s that can be used to index into mem, just like before (this array is allocated statically, but if you wanted to return it from this function you would want to allocate it dynamically instead).

Comment: This is half of the answer. The other half is that the type `int**` allows the compiler to know that the second level _isn't composed of arrays_ but instead of pointers (and at that stage, whether those pointers point to more arrays is irrelevant, as is whether they point to dynamically allocated memory). All the operations that occur from expanding the `[]` notation just smoothly sort themselves out when you consider _types_ at every step, but I really can't be bothered to iterate through every single thing that happens during two varieties of 2D array-like access!

Comment: @Paulpro So let's come back around to if there is a way to use array[][] notation on a single block of dynamically allocated memory as is done with the stack.  The last 2 examples I had seem to do this by letting the compiler make assumptions.  Is this then, how it has to be done in C?

Comment: @MichaelDorgan I'm not sure if you saw my edit, as I made it a few minutes before your comment. I demonstrated a way of allocating a contiguous block of memory and then creating an array of pointers to index into it like a 2D array.

Answer (score 0):

Because the types are completely different.

In the first case, the type in an array with two dimensions, and the length of each dimension is known, so the address can be computed directly, and referenced once.

In the second case, the type is completely different, the type is a double pointer. A pointer to an array of pointers to some type, in your case, an `int`.

All that the compiler knows is that `array` is a pointer to an array, of some unknown size, of pointers to `int`. `array` is a

```
int **array;
```

And `array[x]` is a pointer to an int. Note that it's *just* a pointer to an `int`. It says nothing about how many `int`s it's pointing to.

It can just be a single `int`, or it may not. And each pointer to an `int` could point to a different number of `int`'s.

For example, array[0] may point to ten ints. array[1] may point to twenty `int`s. There's nothing that requires array[x] to point to the same number of `int`s as array[y].

That job belongs to you, the programmer. The compiler doesn't know anything. It is up to you to properly allocate each pointer to an `int`, to the right number of `int`s, for each such pointer, and then allocate the right number of pointers to `int`s in the first place. The compiler doesn't know how many of each there are, it's your job to keep track of that, in some form or fashion, in order to write bug-free code.

Welcome to C++.