# Why does it work to access a dynamically allocated 2D array element with a[i][j]?

Tags: c

Let's say we have declared: `int array[10][6]`. As far as I understand, when you say `array[i][j]`, it translates to `*(((int *)array)+i*6+j)`. But, why does it work if array would be dynamically allocated because to access an element this would be needed: `*(*(array+i)+j)`? I don't understand why `a[i][j]` would work now if it is automatically translated like in the first case.  Thanks.

Comment: check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/917783/how-do-i-work-with-dynamic-multi-dimensional-arrays-in-c. A 2D dynamic array, is an array of pointers in the 1st dimension and a simple type in the 2nd.

Comment: Your first case is an array of arrays, the second is an array of pointers, so it's natural that they're accessed differently.  Arrays are not pointers, pointers are not arrays.

Comment: @molbdnilo well... that's the idea... Why does it work to acces a double pointer with a[i][j]?

Comment: @rptoma The compiler knows whether things are arrays or pointers and adjusts things accordingly. It is not automatically translated like in the first case.

Comment: @molbdnilo hmm, ok. I thought that it translates it like in the first case. It's pretty weird for a newbie, haha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why does it work to access a dynamically allocated 2D array element with a[i][j]?

That's because pointer arithmetic and array indexing are same. Theexpression

```
array[i][j]
```

is equivalent to `*(*(array + i) + j))`. In this expression `array` converts to pointer to its first element and hence becomes of type `int(*)[6]`, i.e. pointer to an array of 6 `int`. Adding `i` to `array` will increment it to `i*sizeof(int[i])` bytes. Therefore, saying `array[i][j]` is translated to `*(((int *)array)+i*6+j)` is wrong.
So, dereferencing `array + i` will give an array of 6 `int` which further will decay to pointer to its first element `array[i][0]` having type `int *`. Therefore, `array[i][j]` is equivalent to  `*(&array[i][0] + j))`

When array is allocated dynamically

```
int **array =  malloc(sizeof(int*)*10);  
for(int i =0; i < 10; i++)
    array[i] = malloc(sizeof(int)*6);
```

then its element can also be accessed using `array[i][j]`. This expression is also equivalent to `*(*(array + i) + j))`. But, the difference here is `array` is of type `int **` and adding `i` to it will increment it by `i*sizeof(int*)`. Dereferencing `array + i` will give `array[i]` which is of type `int *` and hence `array[i][j]` is equivalent to  `*(&array[i][0] + j))`.

That said, in both cases `array + i` increment it to its next element (which can either be of type `int[6]` or `int *`) and finally arithmetic is between `int *` (`&array[i][j]`) and `int` (`j`).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a two-dimensional array like this

```
int a[M][N];
```

then in expressions arrays are implicitly converted to pointers to their first element.

So this expression

```
a
```

has type `int ( * )[N]` and points to the first "row" (element) of the two-dimensional array.

Expression

```
a + i
```

where i some intager in the range `0 - M - 1` point to i-th row of the array

Expression

```
*( i + i )
```

gives the row that is i-th element of the array.

You can write for example

```
printf( "%zu\n", sizeof( a[i] ) );
```

and the statement outputs a value that is equal to `N * sizeof( int )`

On the other hand if this expression

```
*( i + i )
```

is used in other context then as an operand of the `sizeof` operator then it in turn (as it is an array) is converted to pointer to its first element.

Thus expression

```
*( i + i )
```

is implicitly converted to pointer of type `int *` that points to the first element of the i-th row of the original array.

Expression

```
*( i + i ) + j
```

points to th j-th element of the i-th row of the array

As result expression

```
*( *( i + i ) + j )
```

is equivalent to

```
a[i][j]
```

If you dynamically allocated a two dimensional array the following way

```
int ( *a )[N] = malloc( sizeof( int[N][M] );
```

then you at once got the pointer of the same type and having the same value as  the expression shown above for the two-dimensional array

```
a
```

So when you have initially a pointer then the step that implicitly converts a two-dimensional array to a pointer is simply skipped. But the net result will be the same.

If you allocated dynamically an array of pointers the following way

```
int **a = malloc( M * sizeof( int * ) );
for ( size_t i = 0; i < M; i++ ) a[i] = malloc( N * sizeof( int ) );
```

then `a` points to the first element of the dynamically alllocated first array.

```
a + i
```

gives the pointer to the i-th element of the array.

Expression

```
*( a + i )
```

gives the value stored in this element. This value is the address of the i-th allocated array in the loop aboth. It has type `int *`.

So

```
*( a + i ) + j
```

gives the pointer to the j-th element and at last

```
*( *( a + i ) + j )
```

is the unteger value stored in this element.