# difficulty understanding the data structure in meschach library

Tags: c, matrix

I am reading the source code of the [MESCHACH](http://homepage.math.uiowa.edu/%7Edstewart/meschach/) library for matrix and vector computations. Here is the data structure used in the library:

```
/* matrix definition */
typedef struct  {
        unsigned int    m, n;
        unsigned int    max_m, max_n, max_size;
        Real    **me,*base; /* base is base of alloc'd mem */
        } MAT;
```

In here, what is the use of `*base` in the structure ? I mean `**me` is the one containing the matrix and the upper values contain its dimensions, what does the `base` hold.

Code for allocating memory for the matrix:

```
MAT *m_get(int m, int n)
{
   MAT  *matrix;
   int  i;
   
   if (m < 0 || n < 0)
     error(E_NEG,"m_get");

   if ((matrix=NEW(MAT)) == (MAT *)NULL )
     error(E_MEM,"m_get");
   else if (mem_info_is_on()) {
      mem_bytes(TYPE_MAT,0,sizeof(MAT));
      mem_numvar(TYPE_MAT,1);
   }
   
   matrix->m = m;       matrix->n = matrix->max_n = n;
   matrix->max_m = m;   matrix->max_size = m*n;
#ifndef SEGMENTED
   if ((matrix->base = NEW_A(m*n,Real)) == (Real *)NULL )
   {
      free(matrix);
      error(E_MEM,"m_get");
   }
   else if (mem_info_is_on()) {
      mem_bytes(TYPE_MAT,0,m*n*sizeof(Real));
   }
#else
   matrix->base = (Real *)NULL;
#endif
   if ((matrix->me = (Real **)calloc(m,sizeof(Real *))) == 
       (Real **)NULL )
   {    free(matrix->base); free(matrix);
    error(E_MEM,"m_get");
     }
   else if (mem_info_is_on()) {
      mem_bytes(TYPE_MAT,0,m*sizeof(Real *));
   }
   
#ifndef SEGMENTED
   /* set up pointers */
   for ( i=0; i<m; i++ )
     matrix->me[i] = &(matrix->base[i*n]);
#else
   for ( i = 0; i < m; i++ )
     if ( (matrix->me[i]=NEW_A(n,Real)) == (Real *)NULL )
       error(E_MEM,"m_get");
     else if (mem_info_is_on()) {
    mem_bytes(TYPE_MAT,0,n*sizeof(Real));
       }
#endif
   
   return (matrix);
}
```

Why do they first allocate base and use it to allocate `me` ? Also, if you've read the source code, please tell me the use of SEGMENTED in this library. The declaration is in `configure` file.

The matrix structure is defined in `matrix.h` and m_get() is in `memory.c`.

Comment: What is that NEW_A macro defined as?

Comment: #define NEW_A(num,type) ((type *)calloc((size_t)(num),sizeof(type)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I read the code correctly, `me` is a one-dimensional array of pointers to the starts of the "rows" in the matrix: `matrix->me[i] = &(matrix->base[i*n]);` fills the array with the addresses of the respective row at index `i`.

That makes it possible to use `me` with two indices as if it were indeed a two-dimensional array, e.g. write `double d = myMatrix.me[row][column];`. Of course `sizeof(myMatrix.me)` or taking the address of `me`'s elements behaves differently than for a proper 2-dimensional array.

If **`SEGMENTED`** is defined, the memory in the matrix will be allocated row by row and will not be contiguous (and `base` will be null). If you want to pass a raw 2-dimensional array to a library unaware of the `MAT` type the elements will need to lie contiguous in memory. If you just index normally it doesn't matter.

As an aside (I know that this is code from a library, but still): It's funny that just today I was directed to an interesting solution to this problem by Jens Gustedt, https://stackoverflow.com/a/12805980/3150802. He uses a C99 feature, variable length arrays. Interestingly he doesn't actually create any variable length array (instead, he just mallocs like your matrix class) but just uses the run-time length in the *declaration.* Very interesting. The `A` in his post plays the role of `me` in your matrix class, i.e. it's a pointer to one-dimensional arrays which can be indexed twice to obtain a single number from the matrix.

Comment: The trick  is that it *looks* like one, but is completely 1-dimensional. Scrutinize this expression `&(matrix->base[i*n])`: It is a single address value, a number if you want, and it is assigned to an element of `me`. (Using a *single* index). It's true: At the memory location defined by this address there is a whole (one-dimensional) array of REAL again, namely a row of the matrix. Indexing `me` in `me[row]` yields that row, so that we can apply an index to the result of the first index in order to get one element of that row, as in `(me[row])[column]`.