# How do I create a multidimensional array that relies on users input for amount of rows?

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
int NumOfCourses = 0;
int i = 0;
int total = 0;

int main()
{
printf("How many courses");
scanf_s("%d", NumOfCourses);
for (i = 0; i < NumOfCourses; i++)
{
    total += i;
}

int Courses[i][3];
```

It will not let me use i as a value for the rows of my array because it is not a constant.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I work with dynamic multi-dimensional arrays in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/917783/how-do-i-work-with-dynamic-multi-dimensional-arrays-in-c)

Comment: seems to work: http://ideone.com/6qIx31 it is a VLA.

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: Use a compiler that's not 20 years old

Answer (score 1):

The construct you used is called Variable Length Array (VLA). It is mandatory for C99 compiler and optional for C11 compiler. All older versions of C (K&%, C89, C90, C95) do not know VLA. So it depends, which standard your compiler follows. Frequently, compilers know more than one version, and you can select the standard. Try the `-std=c99` option.