# Segfault when populating char* array

Tags: c, matrix, segmentation-fault

I am trying to split a string delimited by '\n' into an array of strings. The string represents an NxN rectangle so each row on the matrix will contain the same number of characters. This is what I have tried:

```
char    **string_to_tab(char *str, int width, int height)
{
    int     i; //counter to scan str
    int     x; //counter for tab column no.
    int     y; //counter for tab row no.
    char    **tab;

    i = 0; //I initialise variables
    x = 0; //separately because I
    y = 0; //like to :P
    tab = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char) * height * width);
    while (y < height)
    {
        while (x < width)
        {
            if (str[i] != '\n' || !(str[i]))
                {
                    tab[y][x] = str[i]; //assign char to char* array
                    x++;
                }
            i++;
        }
        x = 0;
        y++;
    }
    return (tab);
}
```

This gets me a segmentation fault, calling it would look something like this:

```
char *str = "+--+\n|  |\n|  |\n+--+";
char **matrix = string_to_tab(str, 4, 4);
```

Comment: `(char**)malloc(sizeof(char) * height * width);` nope, `malloc` doesn't work like that.

Comment: Please don't edit question code so as to invalidate existing or pending comments/answers.  It's very annoying to those who volunteer effort.

Comment: A lot of possibilities here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/917783/694576

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variable `tab` is a pointer to a pointer, but you reserve a single array of characters with `malloc`. If you want to use `tab` as an array of pointers as in your code, you have to allocate an array of `char` pointers first, and then allocate an array of `char` for each row. But this is complicate.

It should be easier to use `char *tab;` instead, and allocate just an an array of characters as your code does already. You have to change the element access to `tab[y * width + x]` instead of `tab[y][x]`.

Comment: Thank you, your response helped me a lot. I now understand how memory is assigned to n-dimensional arrays a lot better.