# segmentation fault caused by 2d array or strtok

Tags: c, arrays, multithreading, strtok

I am trying to create a thread and read from stdin inside the thread. In `main()` have dynamically allocated memory to a 2d array based on the size given as user input. In the thread I am reading from stdin and splitting it using `strtok` and adding it into the 2d array. I am not sure why there is a segmentation fault, searched SO and I seem to have handled all the cases related to `strtok`.

This is the program -

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int dimB;
int dimA;
char** buffer;
char* temp;


void *thread(void *threadid){
    char *buf;//[30] = {};
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t read;
    char *line = NULL;
    char *each;

   printf("Hello World!.\n");
   while ((read = getline(&line, &len, stdin)) != -1) {

       printf("%s || \n", line);
       each = strtok(line," ,()");
       printf("************************%s ", each);
       while(each != NULL){
               buf = each;
               strcpy(buffer[0][0], buf);
               printf("%s", buf);
           each = strtok(NULL," ,()");
       }

   }
   pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pthread_t tidMpr;
    long r;
    int i;
    dimB = atoi(argv[1]);
    dimA = atoi(argv[2]);
    pthread_t tidRdr[dimA];
    buffer = malloc(dimA * sizeof(char*));
    temp = malloc(dimA * dimB * sizeof(char));
    for (i = 0; i < dimA; i++) {
      buffer[i] = temp + (i * dimB);
    }
//Create thread Thread
    pthread_create(&tidMpr, NULL, thread, NULL);

    free(temp);
    free(buffer);

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

The 2d array memory allocation is from this question - [How do I work with dynamic multi-dimensional arrays in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/917783/how-do-i-work-with-dynamic-multi-dimensional-arrays-in-c).
I know I am writing everything to `buffer[0][0]`, but that is so that I can store `each` in a buffer array `buffer[0][1]`, `buffer[0][2]` later on based on some logic. But that shouldn't be a problem now right?

Also `line` is printing the correct value, whatever it is reading from stdin. So, probably `strtok` is the problem.

Another very similar program produces the desired output. This -

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

typedef struct { char action; int score; } Rules;
Rules rules[5] = {{'P',50}, {'L',20}, {'D',-10}, {'C',30}, {'S',40}};

int findScore(Rules* rules, char action){
  int i;
  for(i=0; i<5; i++){
    if(rules[i].action == action)
      return rules[i].score;
  }
  fprintf(stderr, "Action not present! Exiting...\n");
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  FILE *fp;
  char inputTuple[30] = {};
  char buf[30] = {};
  char* oB;
  oB = "(";
  char* cB;
  char* co = ",";
  cB = ")";
  fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
  int score;
  char *each;
  size_t len = 0;
  ssize_t read;
  char * line = NULL;
  char *eacharray;
  int u = 0;
  char *outputTuple;
  int pad = 0;
  int g;
  if (fp == NULL)
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) {

    each = strtok(line," ,()");
    while(each != NULL){

      if(u%3 == 0){
        outputTuple = (char *) malloc(1 + strlen(each)+ strlen(oB) );
        strcpy(outputTuple, oB);
        strcat(outputTuple, each);
      } else if(u%3 == 1){
        char q = *each;
        score = findScore(rules, q);
      } else if(u%3 == 2){
        char * str3 = (char *) malloc(1 + strlen(outputTuple)+ strlen(co) );
        strcpy(str3, outputTuple);
        strcat(str3, co);
        char *str4 = (char *) malloc(1 + strlen(str3)+ strlen(each) );
        strcpy(str4, str3);
        strcat(str4, each);

        for(pad = strlen(each); pad<15; pad++)
          strcat(str4," ");
        sprintf(buf, "%s,%d)\n", str4, score);
        printf("%s", buf);
        free(outputTuple);
        free(str3);
        free(str4);
      }
      each = strtok(NULL," ,()");
      u++;
    }    
    u = 0;
  }
  fclose(fp);

  return 0;
}
```

Update :
`strcpy(buffer[0][0], buf);` seems to be the problem. When I comment it, it is producing the output. I dont understand why is that causing a problem.

Comment: Hard to tell when you haven't given details about the problem -- like what line was identified in it?

Comment: line is printing the correct value. Whatever it read from stdin.

Comment: @ScottHunter I am trying to store it in different buffers based on a particular input.

Comment: The strcpy fails because you are using a single character value as a pointer; you either meant &buffer[0][0], or the more succinct buffer[0].  When the compiler whines about incompatible integer pointer comparison, it is trying to alert you.