# C fscanf to read each word from a file not working

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, debugging, readfile

I already know how read word by word from a file (using fgets then strok each other), however itd like to find the simplest way and from what Ive seen fscanf, should work.

If fscanf will allocate the pointer of a word inside array[i], why is it not storing anything.

```
Natural Reader is
john make tame
michael george meier
Bonus Second pass
```

Im expecting

```
word = Natural
word = reader
word = is
word = john
...
word = pass
```

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
   int ch;
   int count = 0;
   while ((ch = fgetc(file)) != EOF){
      if (ch == '\n' || ch == ' ')
         count++;
   }
   fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
   size_t size = ftell(file);
   fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);
   char** words = calloc(count, size * sizeof(char*) +1 );
   int i = 0;
   int x = 0;
   char ligne [80];

   while(fscanf(file, "%s", words[i]) != EOF ){ //or != 1
      printf("%s\n", words[i]);
      i++;
   }

   free(words);
   fclose(file);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where exactly do you change `i`?

Comment: Also: how can the output be `word =` something if that `word =` is not even in your code?

Comment: The whole allocation as well as size calculation just seems wrong. You're allocating a contiguous chunk of memory, not an array of pointers (which is very different).

Comment: And do you really *need* an array of words, instead of a single array which you reuse for each word?

Comment: You allocate `<number of words> * <size of the whole file>` bytes. Seems a bit greedy....

Comment: `fscanf(file, "%s", words[i])` without a _width_ specifier is worse than `gets()` and poor programing practice.

Answer (score 2):

`char** words = calloc(count, size * sizeof(char*) +1 );` is not what you'd want, `size` is the number of total bytes in the file, by using `sizeof(char*)` you are multiplying the size you need by the size of a pointer, which will likely give you 8 + 1 times more space than you need, take a good look at `calloc` manual, the first parameter is the number of items, the second is the size of each item.

It will also not give you a 2D array, for that you would need to get the size of each word and allocate each line with the needed space, this would be an obvious overkill just to print the words.

If you want to to read a file to the end word by word and only print the words, you don't need all that, you can use only `fscanf`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    
    if(argc > 1){

        FILE* file = fopen(argv[1], "r"); 
        
        if(file == NULL){
            return EXIT_FAILURE;       
        }

        char word[100];
    
        while(fscanf(file, "%99s", word) > 0){
            printf("%s\n", word);
        }

        fclose(file);
    }
}
```

Note that you should validate `fopen` return and also check the number command line arguments, if you are to use `malloc`, also check its return value.

Notice that I added a width specifier in `fscanf`, this avoids potential buffer overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: because `calloc` does not support allocating memory for 2D arrays and the `words` pointer ends up not working as expected.

Long answer: the call

```c
char** words = calloc(count, size * sizeof(char*) +1 );
```

allocates some memory, fills it with zeros and stores its address at `words`. The value of `words[i]` is then *defined* as "whatever sits in the memory at the position `words+i*sizeof(char*)`". In your case that is zeros, which become `NULL` when they are interpreted as a pointer. `fscanf` requires some valid memory to store whatever it fetches from the file, so when it gets `words[i]` it detects that it's a `NULL` and refuses to write anything there. Then you read from there with `printf` and get a segfault.

For your code to work as intended, you need to dynamically allocate a 2D array of `char`s. That can be done either by allocating a 1D array of pointers to `char` and populating it with pointers to 1D arrays of `char`s (see methods 2 and 4 [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamically-allocate-2d-array-c/)), or by using variable length arrays (Jens Gustedt's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/917783/how-do-i-work-with-dynamic-multi-dimensional-arrays-in-c)).

Or, you could try to avoid using a dynamic 2D array in C. That's what I do unless I absolutely have to. For example, you could replace `char words[X][Y]` with a 1D array `char words[X*Y]`, then obtain `i`th string of the array as `words+i*Y`.