# What is the easiest way to dynamically allocate memory for 2d array?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am curious how the best programmers in the world allocate memory for a 2d array. Any tips and advice will be much appreciated.

PS I am just a student trying to learn.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/917783/how-do-i-work-with-dynamic-multi-dimensional-arrays-in-c

Comment: Funny as accepted answer is not about multi dimensional arrays only arrays of pointers :)

Comment: Is the number of columns per row fixed at compile-time or does this value also have to be dynamic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use array pointers

```
{
    size_t rows = 10;
    size_t cols = 50;

    int (*array)[cols] = malloc(rows * sizeof(*array));

    /* ... */

    free(array);
}
```

Comment: IMO, "how the best programmers in the world allocate memory ..." deserves an allocation success check.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica it is in `/* ... */`