# C++ initialize a 2D primitive array in a class with values from a constructor

Tags: c++, class, compilation, multidimensional-array

I am trying to compile this code:

```
class OthelloState {
public: // constructor 

    Othello(int r, int c);

/* other stuff */

private: // private data

    const int rows;

    const int columns;

    int board[rows][columns];
}
```

I keep ending up with:

```
OthelloState.h:109: error: invalid use of non-static data member 'OthelloState::rows'
OthelloState.h:115: error: from this location
OthelloState.h:115: error: array bound is not an integer constant
OthelloState.h:112: error: invalid use of non-static data member 'OthelloState::columns'
OthelloState.h:115: error: from this location
OthelloState.h:115: error: array bound is not an integer constant
```

I assume that this means I have to make `rows` and `columns` static. But if I make them static, I cannot initialize either with from a constructor, the way I have to for this project...

Is there some other way I can do this?

PS: I know that in real Othello, the board is a square 8 by 8 grid...But after considering how long it would take the computer to generate the next best move on a partial 8 by 8 grid, we are not going to play with "real" Othello board (i.e. no predefined board sizes).

Comment: Not `static`, but "constant and determinable at compile-time".

Comment: Don't you need to initialize `rows` and `columns`? They are `const`s.

Comment: @muntoo I initialized them in the constructor in the cpp file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++, variable length arrays are not allowed. `board[][]` needs to know both of its dimensions at compile time. You can use `vector<vector<int> > board;`, if you want to initialize `row` and `col` at runtime.

```
class OthelloState {
public:
    OthelloState(int r, int c);

private: // private data
    const int rows;  // should be 'unsigned int'
    const int columns;

    vector<vector<int> > board;  
};
```

**Other solution**:

Suppose you know `rows` and `cols` at compile time then you can use `template`. That is as good as initializing `row` and `col` in constructor.

```
template<unsigned int row, unsigned int col>
class OthelloState {
public:
...
private:
  int board[row][col];
};
```

Usage:

```
  OthelloState<8,8> obj;
  OthelloState<10,10> obj;
```

Comment: Could I use your template method without knowing rows and columns at compile time?

Comment: @MatthewD, No. The `template`s can be used only with compile-time information.

Comment: `vector<vector<int> > board[rows][columns];`: Is that syntax C++11?

Comment: @EmileCormier, it was a bad copy paste. Thanks & Edited.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to dynamically define the size of a compile-time, fixed size array at runtime. You will need to dynamically allocate the memory. You also need your constructor to have the same name as your class

```
class OthelloState {
public: // constructor 

OthelloState(int r, int c)
{ 
   board = new int[r];
   for(int i = 0; i < r; i++)
   {
      board[i] = new int[c];
   }
}


/* other stuff */

private: // private data

   const int rows;

   const int columns;

   int **board;
};
```

Make sure you have matching `delete`s for all your `new`s in a destructor if you use this method, though

Comment: I do not recommend this approach. You're just asking for dangling pointer problems. You need to provide a copy constructor and copy assignment so that deep copies are made (or alternatively, make the copy-ctor and assignment private to make the class non-copyable).

Comment: `vector< vector<int> >` does exactly the same thing as this solution without all the memory management pitfalls.

Comment: Yes, proper memory management in required, but it's a solution for creating a _primitive_ 2-d array when the size is not known until runtime. I agree that `vector< vector<int> >` is at least a safer way to create _some_ 2-dimensional matrix, but I don't think it's the best answer to the question as it's stated.

Comment: shouldn't it be board[*i*] = new int[c]; ?

Answer (score 0):

if it's always 8x8, then constants are a minimal solution. here's one way to declare it:

```
class OthelloState {
    // ...
private:
    enum { rows = 8, columns = 8 };
    int board[rows][columns];
};
```

Answer (score 0):

> But after considering how long it would take the computer to generate
>   the next best move on a partial 8 by 8 grid, we are not going to play
>   with "real" Othello board (i.e. no predefined board sizes).

I deduce from that sentence that you're working on a homework assignment. If that's the case, then it might not be possible/practical for you to use [Boost.MultiArray](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/multi_array/doc/index.html) (unless your instructor advised you that it's okay to use Boost).

That leaves `vector< vector<int> >` which are a PITA to initialize properly. Before you can even use `vector< vector<int> >`, you have to loop through each inner vector and resize it.

Boost.MultiArray is basically just an overglorified wrapper around a 1D array of data. I therefore propose a third alternative: Roll up your own 2D wrapper around a flat one-dimensional `vector`. You can overload `operator()` to mimic the `[][]` behavior of 2D arrays:

`int operator()(size_t row, size_t col) {/*compute index into 1D array*/}`

I posted an example of this kind of wrapper [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836425/c-two-dimensional-array-question/5836502#5836502).